# Source with conditon

Tags: terraform

Is it possible to use a source with a condition in terraform modules?

```
module user_creation {
source = local.region == "new_york" ? "./modules/new_york" : "./modules/default_regions"
--
---
}
```

Comment: No; you would need to declare a module with each source and then use a conditional `for_each`, but I would recommend against that kind of scary design pattern.

Comment: Every terraform resource has a `count` option, so you could combine your `default_regions` and `new_york` modules into a single module with a `region` variable and then in each resource that only exists in new_york do  `count = region == "new_york ?  1 : 0 or vice versa.  You can also have multiple module declarations referencing the same source but different variable arguments.

Comment: if the module is deploying resources in a different region , you're probably better off passing the provider configured for that region into the module using a single source with the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Module dependencies in Terraform are static and resolved by `terraform init`, and so cannot vary based on data that will only be known at runtime.

You didn't state what the purpose would be of dynamically selecting a different module, and so I'm going to guess that the idea is that you want to declare users in a different way depending on the region. If so, there are a few different options to achieve that:

- You could design your module that represents the users to have input variables that customize its behavior, and then vary the values you pass to those input variables based on the selected region.

  ```
  variable "region" {
    type = string
  }

  locals {
    region_differences = {
      new_york = {
        something_configurable = 5
      }
    }
    selected_region_differences = local.region_differences[var.region]
  }

  module "users" {
    source = "./modules/users"

    something_configurable = try(
      local.selected_region_differences.something_configurable,
      2, // this is the default value if there is no override
    )
  }
  ```
- You could design your modules so that the "New York users" module is an extension of rather than a replacement for the generic one, and call it using conditional [`count`](https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/count) so that it represents extra resources to declare only in that region:

  ```
  variable "region" {
    type = string
  }

  module "users" {
    source = "./module/users"

    # ...
  }

  module "users_new_york" {
    source = "./module/users/new_york"
    count  = var.region == "new_york"

    # If the New York extension module requires
    # information from the base one, you can
    # declare an input variable of an object type
    # and then pass the module object into it to
    # concisely share the output values from
    # module.users with this module.
    base_users = module.users

    # ...
  }
  ```
- You could write out two module blocks and use conditional [`count`](https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/count) with mutually-exclusive conditions to declare that only one should be instantiated at a time:

  ```
  variable "region" {
    type = string
  }

  module "users_other" {
    source = "./module/users/other_region"
    count  = var.region != "new_york"

    # ...
  }

  module "users_new_york" {
    source = "./module/users/new_york"
    count  = var.region == "new_york"

    # ...
  }

  locals {
    # OPTIONAL:
    # If both of the modules produce compatible output
    # values then it might be helpful to expose whichever
    # one was declared as local.users for use elsewhere
    # in the module without lots of conditional logic.
    # See the "one" and "concat" functions in the Terraform
    # docs to understand how this works.
    users = one(concat(
      module.users_other,
      module.users_new_york,
    ))
  }
  ```

You might find it useful to read the Terraform documentation on [Module Composition](https://www.terraform.io/language/modules/develop/composition) for some other ideas for how to break problems down into smaller parts using Terraform modules.